# Abstraction vs Encapsulation , not the bookish definition , real world examples

Tags: oop, abstract-class, encapsulation, abstraction, object-oriented-analysis

I have searched about this topic everywhere that what's the difference between abstraction and encapsulation

, even one of the most voted stack overflow question , but at the end it seems confusing
for ex - this was an example i found from the internet
Real-World Example

1-->In a car, the abstraction is the steering wheel and pedals; you don’t need to know how the engine works.

2-->car’s engine encapsulates its internal workings; you interact with it through the car’s controls without accessing the engine directly.

the first one is the example of the abstract class and the second one is of encapsulation , i didnot get what's the difference between , both are looking the same

i do not want the bookish definition , i am really confused with it , what's the core difference between two , what points i can think so that both will appear distinct to me

Answer (score 0):

**Example of abstraction**: an `interface Storage` with a method `save`. In fact, we are thinking here about something common between all possible implementations - the interface.

**Example of encapsulation**: `class JdbcStorage` with constructor `JdbcStorage(Connection connection)`. In fact, we are put into “capsule” connection (hiding connection inside an object of the JdbcStorage class).